# javascript id selector is returning null even when the id is present

Tags: javascript, html

Somehow in js in  `const questionEl = document.getElementById('question');` is returning null. I checked all the id selectors and found out that they were all returning null. I cannot understand the cause of the problem. I have elements with the specified id. Then why is still returning null?

```js
const questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
const a_text = document.getElementById("a");
console.log("This  is >>", a_text);
const b_text = document.getElementById("b");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d");

let currentQuestion = 0;

function loadQuiz() {
  console.log(quizData[currentQuestion].question)
  questionEl.innerHTML = quizData[currentQuestion].question;
  currentQuestion++;
}

loadQuiz();
```

```html
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div class="quiz-header">
    <h2 id="question">Question text</h2>
  </div>

  <ul class="quiz-options">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer">
      <label for="a" id="a_text">Question</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer">
      <label for="a" id="b_text">Question</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer">
      <label for="a" id="c_text">Question</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer">
      <label for="a" id="d_text">Question</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button>Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you executing your JS before the page has been rendered?

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but you have `for="a"` on all of your labels.

Comment: Add `defer` to the script tag loading your js, i.e., `<script defer ....>`, because I just ran your code and everything seems to be working

Comment: @j08691 I don't understand how that is possible. I am newbie. I have linked the external js file in html use `script src`

Comment: Is the JS script linked in the head of your page, or at the end before the closing body tag?

Comment: If you put the `<script>` tag in the head, then when it runs the DOM is not yet built, so the target element is not available. There are various ways to deal with this very often asked question.

Comment: @Ameer it worked. Would you mind to tell what this `defer` does?

Comment: For sure, I'll post an answer with more details!

Comment: Like others are pointing out, sounds like it's running before the DOM is loaded, try wrapping it in an event? `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   ...do stuff here...
}, false);`

Comment: Don't defer. Instead do `window.addEventListener("load",loadQuiz);`

Comment: There's a perfectly good duplicate target, we don't need multiple different answers in the comments!

Comment: @Quentin Already closed

Comment: I shifted the script source to the `body` and everything is all fine.

Comment: @AnaghBasak When I made you a snippet, the snippet added the code after the load of the page. That solved the issue so I closed with a dupe